# kendo ui tree - how to show only part of the nodes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have hierarchical data for the tree and I want to show only part of the leaves and later to add more leaves to the tree when a button is clicked for example.

One solution I thought of is to remove all unnecessary items from the data and to add items to the data when I want to add them to the tree view.

I wonder whether there is another solution without adding/removing items from/to the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter) the data source or [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) some of the `.k-item` elements with jQuery.

Comment: I can do that, the problem is that I'll have a lot of unnecessary elements in the dom and I want to avoid that. I'm also using angular.js, I wonder what is better, using ng-if on all of the nodes or adding elements to the dom on demand?

Comment: hard to say without knowing the exact requirements and what you're trying to optimize for; my guess is that it won't matter for the average use case; I'd probably let the Kendo widget handle it by manipulating the data source or using append/remove on the tree view; if you need to find the optimal solution, you'll have to prototype and measure the impact of the various alternatives (although, conceptually speaking, angular doesn't want you to programmatically manipulate the DOM at all)